# Codeigniter Using Form Validation Library Outside of CI

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is it possible to use CI's form validation library outside of CI? I have a onepage site with a contact form and I thought it would be cool to use the library.

My first problem is the library uses get_instance to get the CI super global. Obviously this doesn't exist. Just wondering if anyone has tried this before.

```
$this->CI =& get_instance();
```

This is how I imagine using the library:

```
include('Form_validation.php');
$val = new CI_Form_validation;

$val->set_rules('email', 'Email address', 'required|valid_email');
if ($val->run() == TRUE)
{
    //do something
}
else
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Form validation library class have several depedency classes(Lang, Input, URI, Security and in 2.1 it even need Database packages files) other than Controller class, which contain get_instance() method. Instead hacking it just to validate a single html form, write your own validation class will be a sane option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to toopay's advice I've gone for the simpler route of simply using the functions of the CI validation class that I needed. Woulda been nice though!